# Method not found with custom prototype function

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I need to create a custom prototype almost like jQuery, After a few Google search terms I managed to come across some code I found:

```
var myQuery, $;

(function() {

myQuery = $ = function(selector) {
    return new MyQuery(selector);
};

var MyQuery = function(selector) {
    // Lets make a really simplistic selector implementation for demo purposes
    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName(selector);
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        this[i] = nodes[i];
    }
    this.length = nodes.length;
    return this;
};

// Expose the prototype object via myQuery.fn so methods can be added later
myQuery.fn = MyQuery.prototype = {
    // API Methods
    hide: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        return this;
    },
    remove: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].parentNode.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
        return this;
    },
    hideAll: function(){
      alert("Hiding all.");  
    }
    // More methods here, each using 'return this', to enable chaining
};

}());
```

The code works perfectly, but I need to customize it. At the moment when I do this:

```
myQuery("p").hide();
```

All `<p>` tags are hidden on the page. but when I do this:

```
myQuery.hideAll();
```

I get an error: 
**TypeError: myQuery.hideAll is not a function**

I really just need to be able to allow a selector at times and sometimes I don't need to send through a selector.

Thanks!

Comment: [Works fine for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/2babrfum/) Something else is going on.

Comment: Do you want `myQuery.hideAll()` or `myQuery(…).hideAll()`? The latter already works, the former doesn't need a prototype.

Comment: If you want to emulate jQuery, you should look at the difference between the definition of functions like `$.parseJSON` and methods like `.hide`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the initial answer you accepted, do not assign the entire prototype to your Constructor as static methods! Your prototypical methods are meant to be used for instances of "MyOuery" only.

**Don't use this line:**

```
Object.assign(myQuery, MyQuery.prototype);
```

What that line does is reassign all of the prototype methods onto the actual constructor as static methods. What I mean by this is that now you can do this:

```
myQuery.hide() // That method should not be available at that level
// If you were to call that code right now, you would get this error:
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

The `hide()` method should only be available to instances of MyQuery. You create an instance of MyQuery whenever you call the constructor with a query selector or tag. In other words: `$('div')`. But as you can see, that method is available where it should not be, and is creating errors and potentially bugs for you in the future.

## The correct way to do this:

You need to create a static method on the MyQuery constructor itself, instead of on the prototype.

Take this rework of your code. I've only made a few changes.

```
(function () {
    function MyQuery(selector) {
        if (!(this instanceof MyQuery)) {
            return new MyQuery(selector);
        }

        var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            this[i] = nodes[i];
        }

        this.length = nodes.length;
    }

    // Create the static method here
    MyQuery.hideAll = function () {
        var all = document.querySelectorAll('*');
        for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
            all[i].style.display = 'none'
        }
    };

    MyQuery.fn = MyQuery.prototype = {
        hide: function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                this[i].style.display = 'none'
            }
            return this;
        },
        remove: function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                this[i].parentNode.removeChild(this[i]);
            }
            return this;
        }
    };

    window.myQuery = window.$ = MyQuery;
})();
```

Here is what you can, and can't do with this code:

```
// You can now do this anytime:
$.hideAll();

// But you cannot do this, because the method isn't even available to it
// This gives the following expected error: Uncaught TypeError: $.hide is not a function
$.hide(); // Can't do it from this context! Yay!
```

Once again, the methods that are on the prototype in this case are for instances of MyQuery that need to be used. So, those methods should only be available when instantiating the constructor with a selector.

```
var divs = $('div');
divs.hide().remove(); // Or some other variation.
```

I hope this helps you understand the architecture of your library and the difference between the static methods and the prototypical ones.

Comment: Wow KevBot, this is awesome! The only error I got with this was **TypeError: forEach is not a function** I substituted this with a for() and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Fixed. That error did not show up in Chrome where I worked that up, but did in Firefox and Safari. So, in order to make sure that there's no confusion for others who come across this, I reworked this to use some of the `for` loops and such you were using to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

hideAll is a function of MyQuery object, not myQuery.

I guess you should try
myQuery().hideAll();

myQuery() will return a MyQuery object

Comment: I do not think this is the issue here... `myQuery` returns a new instance of `MyQuery` (see top of OP's code where `myQuery` is defined), so it would indeed have `hideAll` in it.

Comment: myQuery is function that returns a MyQuery object. MyQuery object contains hideAll function. Unless called myQuery is useless.

Answer (score -1):

Well if you want myQuery.hideAll to work here is the quick solution:

```
...
    },
    hideAll: function(){
        alert("Hiding all.");  
    }
    // More methods here, each using 'return this', to enable chaining
};
// you need this line so you can also access the functions without calling myQuery as a function
Object.assign(myQuery, MyQuery.prototype);
```

You cannot right now call myQuery.hideAll() because hideAll is not a function inside myQuery but inside MyQuery.prototype (so you need an instance of MyQuery, which you get by calling myQuery().

Object assign just copies of fields from MyQuery.prototype to myQuery so you can access them without the need of an instance.

LE: Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/udjejgzj/

Comment: This works perfectly as I want it to!!! Thanks tudy23!! 
You say this is a "quick solution", is it not the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: @Rizo It is the correct way of doing this. What I meant by quick solution is that I gave the solution before explaining it. Sorry for making you doubt it.

Comment: No problem, you've saved me a lot of time with this! really appreciate it!